# SSD Cloning Program

Tags: ssd

Looking for a program that will Clone SSD's for me.

I have 5 Identical systems, 4 running Windows 1 running Linux, I want them all to be on Linux and feel like cloning the ssd will be the best way.

Edit - By 5 identical systems I mean the Hardware is the exact same.

not looking to keep anything on the windows systems either.

Comment: This is pretty risk, especially if the hardware varies....but sure try http://clonezilla.org/

Comment: I don't see why this request is SSD specific - anything that can read/write a disk image should work.

Comment: Why not use `dd` to clone the drive from the Linux machine - personally I would get a spare SSD and clone onto that then try swapping it into each machine in turn before committing to overwriting the existing SSDs.